# When creating product attribute which tables affected

Tags: product-attribute, magento2.2.4

I want to delete product attribute but there is a not button like Delete Attribute So please tell me, which tables are affected while creating new product attributes.

Comment: Please specify your Magento version?

Comment: magento version 2.2.4

Comment: please check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it is not recommended to do database operations directly on the database.

But, since you want to know the tables affected by product attributes creation, below is the answer.

Since Magento uses EAV structure for creating and saving product attributes, the first table which is affected by the creation of an attribute is **`eav_attribute`**, which saves the **attribute_code**, **attribute_id**, **backend_type**, **frontend_input** etc.

Since the product entity is related to catalog, so the next table which is affected is **`catalog_eav_attribute`**.

Based on the datatype of the attribute the following tables are affected:

- catalog_product_entity_datetime
- catalog_product_entity_decimal
- catalog_product_entity_gallery
- catalog_product_entity_int
- catalog_product_entity_media_gallery
- catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value
- catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value_to_entity
- catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value_video
- catalog_product_entity_text
- catalog_product_entity_tier_price
- catalog_product_entity_varchar

Please let me know if you want more explanation.